# Java javax.xml.xpath.XPath evaluate does not return nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to filter a XSD document that is part of a larger GUI program, however I want to display certain portions the XSD document only. I'm attempting to query the desired parts of the document using XPath:

**The XSD document is (smaller snippet as, actual doc is much larger):**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <!-- PDS4 XML/Schema for Name Space Id:pds  Version:1.11.1.0 - Wed May 01 17:25:04 PDT 2019 -->
      <!-- Generated from the PDS4 Information Model Version 1.11.1.0 - System Build 9b -->
      <!-- *** This PDS4 product schema is an operational deliverable. *** -->
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://pds.abc.net/pds4/pds/v1"
        xmlns:pds="http://pds.abc.net/pds4/pds/v1"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        version="1.11.1.0">
     
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This XML schema file has been generated from the
          Information Model.</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
     
      <xs:element name="External_Reference" type="pds:External_Reference"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Ingest_LDD" type="pds:Ingest_LDD"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Internal_Reference" type="pds:Internal_Reference"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Local_Internal_Reference" type="pds:Local_Internal_Reference"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_AIP" type="pds:Product_AIP"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Ancillary" type="pds:Product_Ancillary"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Attribute_Definition" type="pds:Product_Attribute_Definition"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Browse" type="pds:Product_Browse"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Bundle" type="pds:Product_Bundle"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Class_Definition" type="pds:Product_Class_Definition"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Collection" type="pds:Product_Collection"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Context" type="pds:Product_Context"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_DIP" type="pds:Product_DIP"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_DIP_Deep_Archive" type="pds:Product_DIP_Deep_Archive"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Data_Set_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Data_Set_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Document" type="pds:Product_Document"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_File_Repository" type="pds:Product_File_Repository"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_File_Text" type="pds:Product_File_Text"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Instrument_Host_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Instrument_Host_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Instrument_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Instrument_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Metadata_Supplemental" type="pds:Product_Metadata_Supplemental"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Mission_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Mission_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Native" type="pds:Product_Native"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Observational" type="pds:Product_Observational"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Proxy_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Proxy_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_SIP" type="pds:Product_SIP"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_SIP_Deep_Archive" type="pds:Product_SIP_Deep_Archive"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_SPICE_Kernel" type="pds:Product_SPICE_Kernel"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Service" type="pds:Product_Service"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Software" type="pds:Product_Software"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Subscription_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Subscription_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Target_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Target_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Thumbnail" type="pds:Product_Thumbnail"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Update" type="pds:Product_Update"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Volume_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Volume_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Volume_Set_PDS3" type="pds:Product_Volume_Set_PDS3"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_XML_Schema" type="pds:Product_XML_Schema"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Product_Zipped" type="pds:Product_Zipped"> </xs:element>
     
      <xs:element name="local_identifier" type="pds:local_identifier"> </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="logical_identifier" type="pds:logical_identifier"> </xs:element>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Agency">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Agency class provides a description of an
            entity that provides regional or national level neternance over
            nodes within the federated Planetary Data
            System.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="pds:name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="description" type="pds:description" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Airborne">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Airborne class provides a description of the
            physical object that transports a platform by or through
            air.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="pds:name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="type" type="pds:type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="description" type="pds:description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Alias">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Alias class provides a single alternate name
            and identification for this product in this or some other
            archive or data system.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="alternate_id" type="pds:alternate_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="alternate_title" type="pds:alternate_title" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="comment" type="pds:comment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Alias_List">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Alias_List class provides a list of paired
            alternate names and identifications for this product in this or
            some other archive or data system.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Alias" type="pds:Alias" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Archival_Information_Package">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Archival Information Package (AIP) class
            defines an Information Package consisting of the Content
            Information and the associated Preservation Description
            Information (PDI), which is preserved within an archive that
            conforms to the Open Archive Information System (OAIS) Reference
            Model.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:restriction base="pds:Information_Package">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="description" type="pds:description" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Ingest_LDD">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Ingest_LDD class provides a form for
            collecting class and attribute definitions.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="pds:name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="ldd_version_id" type="pds:ldd_version_id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="full_name" type="pds:full_name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="steward_id" type="pds:steward_id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="namespace_id" type="pds:namespace_id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="external_property_maps_id" type="pds:external_property_maps_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="comment" type="pds:comment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="last_modification_date_time" type="pds:last_modification_date_time" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="DD_Attribute" type="pds:DD_Attribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="DD_Class" type="pds:DD_Class" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="DD_Rule" type="pds:DD_Rule" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Property_Maps" type="pds:Property_Maps" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Instrument">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Instrument class provides a description of a
            physical object that collects data.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="pds:name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Type_List_Area" type="pds:Type_List_Area" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="type" type="pds:type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="subtype" type="pds:subtype" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="model_id" type="pds:model_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="naif_instrument_id" type="pds:naif_instrument_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="serial_number" type="pds:serial_number" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="description" type="pds:description" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    
      <xs:complexType name="Instrument_Host">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The Instrument Host class provides a description
            of the physical object upon which an instrument is
            mounted.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="pds:name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="instrument_host_version_id" type="pds:instrument_host_version_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="version_id" type="pds:version_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="type" type="pds:type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="naif_host_id" type="pds:naif_host_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="serial_number" type="pds:serial_number" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="description" type="pds:description" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
     
    </xs:schema>
```

Using http://xpather.com/, Im able to test queries to select for example "Injest_LDD", using either:

//complexType[@name='Ingest_LDD']

OR
//xs:complexType[@name='Ingest_LDD']

which finds:

[image]

However using these XPath query patterns in Java returns, no results (XpathResult RETURNS NULL???):

```
     Document partialdoc = db.parse(task.getXsdFile().getFileObject());
                    System.out.println("Document file: " + task.getXsdFile().getFileObject());
                    
                    //ALSO TRIED: //xs:complexType[@name='Ingest_LDD']
                    String expression = "//xs:complexType[@name='" + localPart + "']";
    
                    System.out.println("DEBUG Class MainController, selectedXsdLocalPart(),expression:" + expression);
                    // Given the id, go to correct place in XSD to get all the parameters
                    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                    Node XpathResult = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, partialdoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                    Element e;
                    //XpathResult RETURNS NULL???
                    if (XpathResult != null) {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < XpathResult.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
    
                            if (XpathResult.getChildNodes().item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    
                                e = (Element) XpathResult.getChildNodes().item(i);
                                System.out.println(e.getNodeName() + " = " + e.getNodeValue());
                                sb.append(e.getNodeValue());
                            }
                        }
                        if (!sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("[xs:annotation: null][xs:sequence: null]") && sb.toString().length() > 0) {
                            viewToUpdate.getViewjTextAreaXsd().setText(sb.toString());
                        }
    
                    }
```

How can I select the these complexType elements in XSD using XPath via Java?

Aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When the input documents contains namespaces, you must supply a NamespaceContext object so that the XPath compiler and evaluator has something to resolve the namespace prefixes against. In your case,  a simple implementation like this will probably suffice:

```
static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix.equals("xs"))
            return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then set the context on the XPath object before evaluating any expression:

```
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
```

Then you will be able to select the proper complextType node with this expression:

```
"//xs:complexType[@name='Ingest_LDD']"
```

NB that the prefix used in your code can be different from the prefix used in the input document; it is the mapping to the Namespace URI that is important.

Also: Tools like xpather are ususally "smart", as they can scan the input document and dynamically build a prefix-to-namespace-uri map, and if they are XPath 2.0 compliant, they can usually also deduce a "default" namespace, a concept missing from XPath 1.0 (which is what we still have to deal with plain Java JDK).